# Select2 Js dropdown is not working in durandal Js

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2, durandal-2.0

I am using durandal Js 2.0 & knockout Js.I tried to integrate Select2 Js dropdown in **Durandal**(http://jsfiddle.net/anasnakawa/6XvqX/381/) But its not working. What is custom Binding handlers & how to use it in **durandal**.

```
define([select2],function(select2){
    var activate = function(){ 
    };
return{
activate:activate
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durandal Js uses requireJs to load all the scripts needed. configure your path in main.js and add the script in your viewModel. You also need to add knockout binding handlers in your viewModel.

**viewModel.js**

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'myPath/select2' ], function (router, app, ko, select2) {

    ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).select2(valueAccessor());

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).select2('destroy');
            });
        },
        update: function (element) {
            $(element).trigger('change');
        }
    };

    var DropdownData = ko.observable([]);

    var activate = function () {
        //your code: bind data to observable from ajax call or local repository.
        DropdownData(ko.toJS(data));
    };

    return {
       activate:activate
    };
});
```

**viewModel.html**

```
<select data-bind="options: DropdownData, optionsValue: 'Data_Id', optionsText:'Data_Name',optionsCaption: 'Select...', value:myModel.dropdown, select2:{ }" ></select>
```

for binding handlers, refer this [Knockout Custom Bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)